# CoreData: Accessing Objects through Relationships

Tags: core-data, relationships

Three entities in CoreData:

- `User`
- `EntityA`
- `EntityB`

Relationships:

- `EntityA` has one-to-many Relationship with `User` & inverse
- `EntityA` has one-to-one Relationship with `EntityB` & inverse
- `User` & `EntityB` have no relationships

Objects created:

- `UserA` creates an `objectA` of Type `EntityA` listing `UserB` and UserC as the relationship objects.
- `UserA` also creates `ObjectB` of type `EntityB`, listing `ObjectA`, as its relationship Object

Accessing Objects

- `UserB` logs in and fetches in `EntityA` and successfully downloads `ObjectA`.

Question: Will `UserB` be able access `ObjectB`? If so, can `UserB` access ObjectB with the following code: `NSString *value = [ObjectA.OneToOneRelationshipBetweenEntityAandB valueForkey"@attributeFromObjectB"];`

If not, how can `UserB` access `ObjectB`?  What relationships do I need to establish?

I had asked a similar question earlier but I thought I gave too much information and made it confusing. I deleted that question and hopefully simplified it down to this one.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "User A creates ..." or "User B logs in ..."? Do you have separate databases (persistent stores) per logged-in user? - And have you tried it? Did you experience any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a unified core data model, you can easily access objects as long as there are relationships.

For the purpose of readability, I am redefining your variable / relationship names:

```
User <<-----> Group <<-----> Community
```

Community has many groups has many users. This is simple enough and looks like a viable setup.

To clarify: a user cannot create an object. Only a program can do that.

```
Group *newGroup = [NSEntityDescription 
       insertNewinsertNewObjectForEntityForName:@Group"
       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; 

Community *newCommunity = [NSEntityDescription 
       insertNewinsertNewObjectForEntityForName:@Community"
       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; 


userA.group = newGroup; 
userB.group = newGroup;
newGroup.community = newCommunity;
```

Now both userA and userB belong to newGroup and the group is one of the groups in newCommunity. userB is linked to the group, so it is really easy to access the community:

```
Community *aCommunity = userB.group.community;
```